# Robocopy command line - file with spaces

Tags: command-line, spaces, robocopy

I am trying to run the following command:

```
robocopy.exe \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\test\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap "ADMIN_HEADER.CFM" "new folder\NEW TEXT 3.TXT" /mir /log:\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfei\mysync2\logs\rc_09032013_lrobinson33_1.txt /NDL /r:2 /w:2
```

From this I get:

Started : Wed Sep 04 09:32:22 2013

Source - \eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap\
     Dest - \eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\test\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap\

```
Files : ADMIN_HEADER.CFM
```

Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

---

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "new folder\NEW TEXT 3.TXT"

Can anyone give me the correct syntax for dealing with spaces in the folder AND file name?

Comment: `robocopy . c:\temp "file with spaces" "other file with spaces.txt"` works for me. Can you show your exact command that **doesn't** work?

Comment: robocopy.exe \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\test\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap ADMIN_HEADER.CFM NEW FOLDER (2)\NEW TEXT DOCUMENT.TXT /mir /log:\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mysync2\logs\rc_09032013_1.txt /NDL /r:2 /w:2

Comment: I don't see quotes in that statement?

Comment: That was my orignal statement. I've tried many different variations.

obocopy.exe \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\test\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap ADMIN_HEADER.CFM "NEW FOLDER (2)\NEW TEXT DOCUMENT.TXT" /mir /log:\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mysync2\logs\rc_090320‌​13_1.txt /NDL /r:2 /w:2

obocopy.exe \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\test\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap "ADMIN_HEADER.CFM NEW" "FOLDER (2)\NEW TEXT DOCUMENT.TXT" ...

Comment: ROBOCOPY handles spaces in file names just fine as long as each file name is enclosed in quotes. Edit your question, and show the exact command with quotes that is failing.

Comment: c:\Windows\System32>robocopy.exe \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap \\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\test\cfapps\cfeis\mybeap "ADMIN_HEADER.CFM" "new folder\NEW TEXT 3.TXT" /mir /log:\\eisdevl.nas.gatech.edu\coldfusion\devl\cfapps\cfei\mysync2\logs\rc_09032013_lrobinson33_1.txt /NDL /r:2 /w:2 <br> 
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "new folder\NEW TEXT 3.TXT"

Answer (score 8):

The ending backslash \ on the directory isn't allowed.  Just specify the full path without the ending \ on it. You can use the "pathnames" in quotes just fine then.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose everything in double quotes that will have spaces or other poison characters.  They can also be used with short names safely.

```
robocopy.exe "<fromdir>" "<todir>" "file.cfm" "new file 3.cfm" /mir /log:"#path#\cfeis\mysync2\logs\rc_090313.txt" /NDL /r:2 /w:2
```

Comment: I've realized that the issue is not the spaces, but the fact that I am specifying a directory in the files list. I guess I can only specify a directory in the source.destination. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

c:\Program" "Files

Would be the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks New Guy.  I had this:

```
robocopy "%source%\Core" "%destination%\Core" Start.br Client.br Menu.br Check File Versions.br
```

trying to get the four files:

1. Start.br
2. Client.br
3. Menu.br
4. Check File Versions.br

But it just wouldn't work until I tried your trick: (notice the new double quotes)

```
robocopy "%source%\Core" "%destination%\Core" Start.br Client.br Menu.br Check" "File" "Versions.br
```

Now it works great.  Don't think I ever would have thought to try that befoe.